# How to stop a repeat until function from stopping the program right away in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a piece of code that moves the first digit of a user-inputted number to the back of the number (ex. 125 to 251), and I want it to display all the possible combinations of this. (ex. if I enter 125, then it will display 251, 512, and 125). I tried using the while - if function (python's version of a repeat until function), but this just make the program stop after displaying only one number (ex. i entered 125 and it gave 251 before stopping). Here's my code:

```
n = 1
num = input("number: ")

while n == 1:

    length = len(num)
    intnum = int(num)
    intnum2 = intnum
    x = int(intnum2 // 10**(length-1))
    s = (intnum2 - x*(10**(length-1)))
    l = s*10
    final = (l+x)
    print(final)
    final = intnum2
    if final == intnum:
        break
else:
    print("Done")
```

If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Understanding the number of combinations will help you solve the problem. @Unknown

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Turning it into an integer is just making this harder, you just need to print the string `num[1:] + num[0]` until you're back at the original value

Comment: It's math. How many combinations will a n digit number have when the digits are shuffled. @Sayse also has a good point.

Comment: I'm not trying to shuffle it. I'm trying to move the first digit to the back of the number for a circular primes program I'm making.

Comment: @Sayse Can you show me how to do that? I'm really new to python (I started learning about a month ago).

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with using your number as a `string`, here's a shorter way. Just append the first character to the end of the rest of the characters repeatedly

```
num = input("number: ") 
for _ in range(len(num)): 
    num = num[1:]+num[0] 
    print(num) 
print('Done')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
import itertools
num = input("number: ")
perms = [''.join(combs) for combs in itertools.permutations(num)]
print(perms)
```

**input**

> number: 153

**output**

> ['153', '135', '513', '531', '315', '351']